# renderSlickR: slickR adds plot below the previous plot, instead of replacing it

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to use renderSlickR to create a carousel of figures based on input selections. The carousel works fine and is reactive to the input, until I add the `dots = TRUE` option to slickR settings. In this case, plots don't replace each other. Rather, a new plotted is generated below the previous one, each time the input is changed. I have re-created my problem using iris data:

```
# Load required packages
if (!require(pacman))
  install.packages("pacman")

#Not all these packages are needed here, obviously
pacman::p_load(
  R.devices,
  shiny,
  magrittr,
  dplyr,
  ggplot2,
  shinyWidgets,
  svglite,
  slickR,
  ggpubr
)

# Load iris dataset
data(iris)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar panel for inputs
  sidebarPanel(
    # Select x-axis variable
    selectInput("choice", "X-axis variable", choices = c(100, 150)),
  ),
  # Main panel for output
  mainPanel(
    # Plot output
    slickROutput("plot")
  )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    fig_list = list()
    for (i in 1L:2L){ #Creating two plots to make a carousel
      fig_list[[i]] <- 
        {
          svglite::xmlSVG(
            code = {
              g = ggplot(iris[(40*i):input$choice, ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                                                     y = Petal.Length)) +
                geom_point() 
              print(g)
            },
            standalone = T)
        }
    }
    output[["plot"]] = renderSlickR({
      slickR(fig_list, "plot") +
        settings(
          customPaging = htmlwidgets::JS(
            "function(slick,index) {
                            return '<a>'+(index+1)+'</a>';
                       }"
          ),
          dots = T #if we remove this, then only one plot is generated.
        )
    })
    
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm not sure if there's any other way to include dots or numbers under the carousel. If this is the only way, I'd be great if I find the solution. Thanks!

**Update:**
the issue was previously addressed in [SlickR github](https://github.com/yonicd/slickR/issues/70). Trying [this patch](https://github.com/yonicd/slickR/commit/1ab229e4c400e54187a406130610852b0300986c) solved my issue!

Comment: Weird (+1) Wondering whether this is a bug.

Comment: May I clarify. You want all for plots in one place with four dots?

Comment: @TarJae I want the carousel to be shown that is based on current selection. Right now, if you switch between selections multiple times, you will have multiple carousels. But the point of selection is to keep information related to the current selection only.